# Is this Visual Fox Pro Return statement valid?

Tags: visual-foxpro, foxpro, dbase

I'm working on converting a visual fox pro/dbase application to PHP/mysql, and I noticed that for the programs there is one return that has a right arrow after it.  I'm thinking that it's just a typo, but wanted to see if anyone was familiar with a return statement have a right arrow after it.  Like maybe it returns particular data from the program.

```
RETURN->
```

Comment: Having the arrow after RETURN has no special meaning. VFP is pretty good about ignoring garbage after a command, so it might not cause an error, either.

Comment: Thank you for the information.

Comment: I would disagree with all my respect. It wouldn't be ignored but cause a syntax error.

Comment: Cetin's right. At least in VFP 9 SP2: RETURN-> and RETURN -> both error.

Comment: Which VFP version is the original code in?

Comment: Not sure about the original version, but I'm opening it with VFP 9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking at a PRG it most likely is just an end of file indicator.  Which means just ignore it.  I believe it is in the preferences that you would indicate you do not want to see this.

Answer (score 1):

-> is an indirector but needs to have an object and a property in that case (old style dot notation, now . is used instead), ie:

```
Return = CreateObject("empty")
AddProperty(m.return, 'dummy', 'Hello')
? return->dummy
 * is the same as:
? return.dummy
```

Doing such a thing would be an awful practice but that is another matter.

If you set aside the above case, likely in yours it is a typo and leaving it like that would produce error.